# Compare two arrays and return the difference in Dataweave

Tags: dataweave, mule4

I want to compare two arrays based on an ID and return the array2 in case of any difference along with the ID.

Array1:

```
[
  {
    "EmpNo": "00016610",
    "Project": "ABC",
    "Country": "USA",
    "EmailAddress": "sd@abc.com"
  },
  {
    "EmpNo": "100280",
    "Project": "XYZ",
    "Country": "USA",
    "EmailAddress": "ab.cd@abc.com"
  }
]
```

Array2:

```
[
  {
    "EmpNo": "00016610",
    "Project": "ABC",
    "Country": "CA",
    "EmailAddress": "sd1@abc.com"
  },
  {
    "EmpNo": "100280",
    "Project": "XYZ",
    "Country": "USA",
    "EmailAddress": "ab.cd@abc.com"
  }
]
```

Expected Output:

```
[
  {
    "EmpNo": "00016610",
    "Project": "ABC",
    "Country": "CA",
    "EmailAddress": "sd1@abc.com"
  }
]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are all the keys always the same for every element in the arrays?

Comment: Yes all the keys are always same for both the arrays

Answer (score 1):

You can use [diff](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.3/dw-diff-functions-diff) to return the differences between two objects and can work with the output of that to achieve your goal.

Something along the lines of

**Script**

```
%dw 2.0
import diff from dw::util::Diff
output application/json
var arr1=   [
  {
    "EmpNo": "00016610",
    "Project": "ABC",
    "Country": "USA",
    "EmailAddress": "sd@abc.com"
  },
  {
    "EmpNo": "100280",
    "Project": "XYZ",
    "Country": "USA",
    "EmailAddress": "ab.cd@abc.com"
  }
]

var arr2= [
  {
    "EmpNo": "00016610",
    "Project": "ABC",
    "Country": "CA",
    "EmailAddress": "sd1@abc.com"
  },
  {
    "EmpNo": "100280",
    "Project": "XYZ",
    "Country": "USA",
    "EmailAddress": "ab.cd@abc.com"
  }
]
---
diff(arr2,arr1)
```

**Output**

```
{
  "matches": false,
  "diffs": [
    {
      "expected": "\"sd@abc.com\"",
      "actual": "\"sd1@abc.com\"",
      "path": "(root)[0].EmailAddress"
    },
    {
      "expected": "\"USA\"",
      "actual": "\"CA\"",
      "path": "(root)[0].Country"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: you could as well do arr2 -- arr1 and that should output your expected result as well